# Scala HashSet or HashMap to implement a cache of Strings?

Tags: scala, caching, hashset

In my current code I see a lot of String IDs cached as:

```
val idMapping = MMap.empty[String, String]
idMapping.put("ID1234", "ID1234")
```

This is supposedly done as a performant way of caching these unique ID for quick retrieval like -

```
idMapping.get("ID1234")
```

and If it returns null then blah blah.

Is there a better alternative to this? HashSet comes to my mind readily but I find scant HashSet based cache examples in Scala?

Can anybody suggest improvements to the above design?

Comment: It looks more like a 'lookup' than key-value cache. For cache, use a map, for lookup use a set, either [immutable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Set) or [mutable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Set) - there is a [mutable `HashSet`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.HashSet)

Comment: If the keys and values are identical, why would you need to look anything up as opposed to just using the key as-is? Is it for validation or something?

Comment: The collection acts as a store for IDs that have already been actioned upon. If we receive an ID that is already in the collection, we just ignore it. I am just confused by the reason for using a Map to achieve this. Could there have been a just reason for doing this or is it just plain wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Set`. If it really always is an identity mapping, a `Map` is completely unnecessary. It consumes more memory and can be slower, when you use `get`, because of the creation of the `Option` value. Also checking `if (alreadyProcessed(key))` just looks nicer than `if (alreadyProcessed.get(key).nonEmpty)`.

Answer (score 3):

The best data structure for caching is WeakHashMap.

In your example:

```
val cache = new WeakHashMap[String, String]

/* … */

val value = cache.getOrElseUpdate(id, generate(id))
```

WeakHashMap does not protect the keys from garbage collection, which means that entries will be automatically deleted when they are no longer in use and some garbage collection occurs. mutable.HashMap can be used instead (`getOrElseUpdate` is also available) if memory is not an issue.

Comment: My question is focused more on if a repetetion of type `idMapping.put("ID1234", "ID1234")` is really necessary? Can there be a fast hashed collection (comparable to Map) without duplicating the keys as values ?